# Remove image caption from post excerpt

Tags: posts, excerpt, captions

I am currently using a wordpress plugin called "limit-posts" to better customize my post excerpts. The only issue I have is the excerpt is including the caption text from the image that is within the post.

I can see in the code that all captions are enclosed in  tags

Is there a way I can strip out the any content within em tags from the post excerpt?

Here is a link to the current plugin in use - http://labitacora.net/comunBlog/limit-post.phps

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand the caption is a shortcode, so wrap get_the_content(...) inside `strip_shortcodes()` and it should remove it...

Answer (score 1):

You can always simply hide it with CSS.
It's not a perfect solution but may be sufficient for your case.

CSS class of the caption paragraph is `.wp-caption-text`

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use something like this at all. There are plenty of hooks for content and excerpt retrieval to use, I see absolutely no need to drop native functions in favor of something else.

You can use `excerpt_length` filter to change excerpt length (in words) or `the_excerpt` to make changes to excerpt's text before output.

If I may ask - what is your technical level with WordPress? Do you want some code examples for this? If so please write out how exactly you want excerpt modified.